# Good tools that fit on a thumb drive

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I have been on the lookout lately for some good tools to fill up my [flash drive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_flash_drive) and I thought I would ask the Server Fault community for recommendations on good tools that will fit onto a thumb drive.

Some I use are [Driver Packs](http://driverpacks.net), [CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/) and the [portable apps suite](http://portableapps.com/).

Comment: If this were SO I would say notepad++.  But, alas, I am at a loss.

Comment: A good text editor is critical for server admin too I think

Comment: For what OS? [this comment does not need 15 characters]

Comment: Any OS that uses config files longer than 15 lines long!

Comment: Wish that people would add items individually to a question like this because otherwise everyone posts huge lists which everyone eventually just gives up reading.

Comment: congrats on the first gold-badge in serverfault! http://serverfault.com/badges/36/stellar-question

Comment: This question doesn't specify the use-case (in what situation would you use this USB? Would it be for webserver admin? Or just to carry around with you for diagnosing problems on other machines? Or something else entirely?), O/S (Try running an exe in Linux without additional tools), dependencies (do you expect to already have python? perl? ruby? PHP?). Furthermore, I don't know whether it's a good idea to use rewritable media for software like that, anyway. Better to use ROM so that, if a machine later is found to be infected, the infection hasn't spread via the USB.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

These are the utilities I have on my drive:

- [CurrPorts](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html) displays the list of
  all currently opened TCP/IP and UDP
  ports on your local computer.
- [ftpserver3lite](http://www.pablosoftwaresolutions.com/html/quick__n_easy_ftp_server_lite.html) is an FTP server
- [ftpwanderer2](http://www.pablosoftwaresolutions.com/html/ftp_wanderer.html) is an FTP client
- [ipnetinfo](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/ipnetinfo.html) answers questions
  about an IP address: owner,
  country/state, range, contact info,
  etc.
- [miranda](http://www.miranda-im.org/) general messaging
  solution (supports most [P2P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer) messaging
  networks)
- [omziff](http://www.xtort.net/xtort-software/omziff/) encryption decryption
  tool.
- [FoxitReader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/reader/) wonderful
  alternative to adobe's PDF reader.
  light and fast and portable.
- [Qm (The Quick Mailer)](http://davidp.ordinarylight.com/qm/) if you
  just want to send an Email the old
  pasion way with no installation.
- [Restoration](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/restoration.html) quick and basic
  undelete utility.
- [smsniff](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/smsniff.html) basic TCP sniffer.
- [torpark](http://lifehacker.com/software/web-browser/download-of-the-day--torpark-15-windows-202981.php) a Firefox-based browser
  for completely discrete browsing.
- [treepad](http://www.treepad.com/) just a nice utility to
  organize your data in, much like
  freemind and other [mind maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_map).
- [cpicture](http://cpicture.net/en/) a picture viewer
- [DriveMan](http://www.alexnolan.net/software/driveman.htm) for managing hard
  drives on the local computer.
- [FollowMeIPLite](http://www.fmip.org/download.php) very much like
  www.whatismyip.com only much quicker.
- [hfs](http://www.rejetto.com/hfs/) opens a small HTTP file
  server from desired folder, for
  instant file sharing.
- [angry ip scanner](http://www.angryziber.com/w/Download) scans IP's
- kill.exe - needs no introduction :)
- [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) a telnet utility every system
  administrator has got to be familiar with.
- [startup control panel](http://www.mlin.net/StartupCPL.shtml),
  [StartupList](http://startuplist.en.softonic.com/), regcleaner -
  really there are many registry
  cleaners/managers out there, lots of
  them fits nicely in a thumb-drive.
- [Revealer](http://www.rekenwonder.com/revealer.htm) reveals passwords from
  password fields. It is very useful in many
  situations.
- [vncviewer](http://www.realvnc.com/cgi-bin/download.cgi?product=free4/vncviewer/win) client for the VNC
  remote desktop protocol
- [WinAudit](http://www.pxserver.com/WinAudit.htm) audits a Windows
  machine. Lots of useful information.
- xcopy.exe - it is still useful to have
  around.
- [TcpView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) shows all all TCP and UDP endpoints on your system.

[Beyond Compare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_Compare) is fantastic, btw. Also, you might want to check out [portable freeware](http://www.portablefreeware.com/).

Comment: So is Qm for sending email the old fashion way, or the old passion way ;)

Considering how frustrating the old days could be, sometimes you *did* have to be passionate about it!

Comment: for HFS, be sure to use the beta version for additional functions.

Answer (score 45):

[Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/), brilliant for checking for changes

Comment: Beyond Compare is one of the applications I'd want to have with my if I were stranded on a desert island. Er, with a computer.

Comment: Is that still shareware? I propose WinMerge, which is freeware...

Comment: It's worth buying and does a lot more than winmerge - I use it to test failed file transfers of large trees, but it can even go as far as showing you what's different in photos

Comment: @dthrasher If I were stranded on a desert island with a computer, I'd want some solar power and satellite internet.

Answer (score 45):

Most [Previously SysInternals Tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx)

Also Kudos to Palmin for mentioning "[Sysinternals Live](http://live.sysinternals.com/)", in the comments. (see [live.sysinternals.com/About_This_Site.txt](http://live.sysinternals.com/About_This_Site.txt))

Comment: Might be worth to also mention "Sysinternals Live", see http://live.sysinternals.com/About_This_Site.txt

Answer (score 32):

In top of that, I strongly recommend to add [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) if you keep any personal or confidential data. Sometimes I need to put customer's database backups and I'd be in great trouble if someone gets access to them.

Answer (score 31):

I got these from [crazeegeekchick.com](http://crazeegeekchick.com/blog/25-must-have-thumb-drive-apps-for-geeks/) some time ago and I really love them.

1. [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) – encrypt your thumb drive to protect your information
2. [ToDoList](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/todolist2.aspx) – A task management tool that allows you to repeatedly sub-divide your tasks into more manageable pieces 
   whilst still presenting a clean and intuitive user experience. (Windows Only)
3. [Portable Firefox](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable) – Leaves no personal information behind on the machine - you can take along your browser/extensions/bookmarks anywhere
4. [Pidgin Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/pidgin_portable) – All-in-one instant messaging (supports AIM, ICQ, MSN Messenger, Yahoo, G-Chat, etc)
5. [WS FTP32](http://www.chicopee.com/pbbs/) – ftp client
6. [FileZilla](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/filezilla_portable) – yet another ftp client
7. [Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html) – a fast light-weight advanced text editor with syntax highlighting
8. [Notepad++](http://portableapps.com/apps/development/notepadpp_portable) - this is one of my favorite text editors – now made portable
9. [Color Cop](http://colorcop.net/features/) – this is one of my favorite freeware apps – includes an eyedropper you can drag over any window to grab the color value. It then offers a palette of 42 complimentary colors to the one you've picked.
10. [Ifranview](http://www.irfanview.com/) – a light little graphics viewer/editor that packs a big punch. You can use it to work with screen captures, create slideshows and more
11. [GIMP](http://portableapps.com/apps/graphics_pictures/gimp_portable) – the popular open source image editor packaged as a portable app – very robust
12. [7-Zip Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/7-zip_portable) – handles zip, gzip, tar, rar etc
13. [Allway Sync](http://allwaysync.com/) – syncs files between your thumb drive and PC
14. [Unknown Devices](http://www.halfdone.com/Development/UnknownDevices/) – helps you find out what the unknown devices in the device manager are
15. [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download) – data recovery software that can recover lost partitions or make drives bootable again
16. [UTorrent](http://www.utorrent.com/) – my preferred bit torrent client – I love having this with me wherever I go
17. [Roeder's .NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/index.htm) – recently purchased by Red Gate, this still-free app can be used to explore .NET assemblies, understand relationships between classes and methods, find where types are instantiated and exposed or check that code has been correctly obfuscated before release. There are also over 30 add-ins available.
18. [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) – formerly Filemon and Regmon, this is an invaluable sleuthing tool
19. [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/download.html) – based on the popular VNC remote control software, this version can live on a thumb drive
20. [WinMerge](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/winmerge_portable) – compares differences between files and merges changes. It has the same features as the desktop version
21. [Text2Html](http://www.cybermatrix.com/text2html.html) – a text to HTML converter – converts text files into HTML format
22. [Portable Apps Suite](http://portableapps.com/suite) – this is the mac-daddy of them all – it includes Firefox, Thunderbird(email), Sunbird(calendar),ClamWin (antivirus), Pidgin(see above), Sumatra PDF Readable, KeePass Password Safe, OpenOffice, CoolPlayer (audio Player) and even a couple of games
23. [Restoration](http://www.snapfiles.com/reviews/Restoration/restoration.html) – Recover accidentally deleted files – even after they were deleted from the recycle bin
24. [Infra Recorder Portable](http://infrarecorder.sourceforge.net/?page_id=5) – cd and dvd burning
25. [RockXP](http://www.rockxp.org/) – allows you to recover windows passwords or keys, change keys, display system password, and more – sneaky!

Comment: Nice list. I know I can search for these, but I'm lazy. If you provided links, you'd get an upvote...

Comment: same DBKK, same :)

Comment: The link for ToDoList is wrong.  It should be http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/todolist2.aspx.  I'd fix it myself, but I don't have enough rep yet ;)

Comment: The ToDo List link has been updated.

Comment: Filezilla is better than WS_FTP any day of the week.

Answer (score 22):

*[**Update**: Initially I deleted this answer because I spotted it was already mentioned in the question. However I think it would be good for it to see votes so I have checked the Community Wiki box to prevent people from thinking I'm trying to game the system]*

Apps from http://portableapps.com/ like Portable Firefox leave no trace on the system you run them on.

Also the PortableApps app itself makes using them a piece of cake.

Comment: this is the site i refer everyone to so that they dont have to pay for unneeded software on the internet.

Answer (score 22):

What **doesn't** fit on a thumb drive, these days? 16GB drives are like $50!

Comment: No, the price has gone down significantly since you have posted your answer. You can get one for like $20USD

Comment: Perhaps the question should be changed to "RUN on a thumb drive." As in portable.

Comment: It is not so much space constraints but as for use. For example the use of driverpacks on your own computer doesnt make much sense as drivers dont just get up and walk away while they have alot of use on a flash drive

Answer (score 18):

[Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_USB) (e.g. [Debian](http://www.debian.org/), [Knoppix](http://www.knoppix.net/), [Puppy](http://www.puppylinux.com/)).  Even if the systems you're working with aren't Linux, you can get useful things done by having a full, working OS in your pocket; sometimes having a different OS can even be an advantage.

Comment: Yes, especially one that identifies/diagnoses hardware even before it boots up.

Comment: Yes, especially if you need to get to a NTFS file that is behind an unknown password.

Comment: Also, usually those linux images have also useful software that is actually unrelated to linux like memtest86.

Answer (score 18):

Wireshark - monitor network traffic.

Answer (score 15):

In addition the Sysinternals, AVG, Portable Firefox and PuTTY mentioned above my USB key contains:

- [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) - for hunting down large files and directories on hard drives
- [Stinger](http://vil.nai.com/vil/stinger/) - for killing common virus infections

Answer (score 14):

One of my most-used tools on my USB-Stick:

[RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/?aff=jatwood)
It's about the easiest and quickest (regex) find/replace tool available.

Comment: Is this really useful to a SysAdmin? A programmer I can understand but not sure what value this has to the target audience of ServerFault.

Comment: A ton of sysadmin work is done at the command line, and deals with log files.  Finding that needle in the haystack in minutes while other admins take hours gives you a significant edge in solving a critical issue.

Comment: How about Strawberry Perl? :D http://xkcd.com/208/

Comment: What's with the "aff=jatwood" portion of the URL?  Is Huppie another Jeff Atwood account?

Comment: Nope, but if you'll link them you might as well sponsor one of your favorite bloggers.

Comment: I use a tool called WildReplace that would give it a run for its money...

Answer (score 8):

A decent text editor (eg. notepad++). Process Explorer.

Answer (score 8):

I usually keep about a dozen different types of boot-images on my USB (and yes, it doesn't cost an arm and a leg to buy all this stuff):

- DOS boot for Ghost (for old computers)
- DOS boot with CDROM
- [SpinRite](http://grc.com)
- Small [BartPE](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/) with Ghost
- [memtest86](http://memtest86.com)
- [Offline NT Password Recovery](http://home.eunet.no/pnordahl/ntpasswd/) boot

The main reason being that when you work with governmental organizations, you can't always get access to the Internet, but (for me) it was easy to burn CDs there. It made debugging bad hardware, and problemtic OSs much easier.

Answer (score 8):

Definitely [Total Commander](http://ghisler.com). Just runs out of the install folder; does packing/unpacking, FTP, file diff, folder sync, multi-rename, checksum generation/verification. You name it...

For those who still own POP3 accounts; [E-Res-Q](http://magnetiq.com/e-res-q/) (shameless plug!) allows no-frills access to a POP3 account for quick viewing and cleanup of messages (good for clearing spammed out or blocked-with-a-50MB-attachment accounts).

Answer (score 7):

[DosBox](http://www.portablefreeware.com/?id=687) of course, for when you need to emulate an old ODS machine for, umm, old office applications.

Comment: Games. I mean old games.

Comment: Don't we all want to stick with WordPerfect 5.1 :')

Comment: actually in israel there are probably several DOS station still at work. some hebrew applications problems (printing mostly) of 'back then' were solved in such a not-elegant, un-upgradeable manner that they have to keep them untill they completely replace the system. israeli insurance agents know what i'm talking about.

Answer (score 7):

- [UltraEdit & UltraCompare](http://www.ultraedit.com/products/ue3.html) are a great text editor and file/folder comparison tool, and they both support U3.
- [Keepass](http://keepass.info/) for my password management.
- [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx) tools should go without saying...

Answer (score 6):

Aside from SysInternals, utilities from [Nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/) are also useful.

Comment: Yes. Sysinternals and Nirsoft. A lovely combination.

Answer (score 6):

Installers for perl and vim

Comment: never leave hone without it

Answer (score 5):

Portable Total Commander is a must have for any portable environment.

Answer (score 5):

Win32 GNU tool set

Answer (score 4):

[AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com) can be placed on and run from your flashkey.

There are many things you might script an ability to do which might ease Server related tasks.

Comment: One of my favorite tools of all time (apart from the painful variable syntax).  Of course you don't even need Autohotkey itself if you compile your scripts into executables.

Answer (score 3):

I really like http://portableapps.com/ for this.

Answer (score 3):

This question is 7 hours old, and no one have mentioned a *hex (binary) editor* yet. Sometimes, even a sysadmin needs to look inside a file to check (or tweak) what *realy* lurks inside.

Lightweight but a little old, [frhed](http://www.kibria.de/frhed.html) a is free binary file editor for Windows.

[HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) is a carefully designed and fast hex editor, seems more current.

Answer (score 3):

Make a thumb drive that is bootable to Ubuntu.

Comment: I use Fedora 10 (slower than 9, unfortunately), but +1. Do you do a fresh install or use the USB-installer thingy? I do a plain install, even if I have to manually set up GRUB.

Comment: Oooh, sorry for dogging you on the reply for so long!  Didn't notice.  Fresh install.

Answer (score 3):

For constantly updated info on this, check out

http://lifehacker.com/tag/portable-applications/

Answer (score 2):

[Directory Opus](http://www.gpsoft.com.au), it feels like half of your computer is always with you.

Comment: +1 best Windows sysadmin tool there is - and it has a thumbdrive export option, can it be better? ^^

Answer (score 2):

Maybe take a look on [Framakey](http://framakey.org/En/FramaKey) which is a compilation of modified program to use them on a USB stick.

It currently includes :

- Firefox
- Thunderbird
- OpenOffice.org 2.0b
- VLC
- Coolplayer
- Scite

Comment: Not much there (anything) that you can't get from PortableApps (http://portableapps.com) individually.

Comment: Firefox is the best!

Answer (score 2):

The Computer Repair Utility Kit that Technibble put together has most of the essential tools you'd need. It's been designed so that the tools can run from a USB drive. Unfortunately, they no longer distribute the toolkit themselves, but you can probably find a copy elsewhere.

http://www.technibble.com/computer-repair-utility-kit/

Technibble also has lots of reviews of sysadmin tools.

http://www.technibble.com/categories/computer-repair-tools/

Comment: This is one of the best sets of repair tools out there. I use it on a daily basis.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say having a bootable WinPE image is crucial for desktop/server support.

Answer (score 2):

[Far manager](http://www.farmanager.com/), of course, besides the stuff other mentioned. It is like Total Commander, but what is interesting about it is that it is a Windows console application - but it displays full UI.

Comment: oops. I didn't see yours before I added mine. 
FAR makes windows usable efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

To mention a few I don't yet see listed:

[WhyReboot](http://exodusdev.com/products/WhyReboot/) (reports restart queued operations)
[CPUID's CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/cpuz.php) (hardware info)
[CloneSpy](http://www.clonespy.com/?Features) (duplicate files)
[Scanner](http://www.steffengerlach.de/freeware/) (disk usage)

I also second [@John](https://serverfault.com/questions/261/good-tools-that-fit-on-a-thumb-drive/376#376)'s recommendation for the suite of tools by [NirSoft](http://nirsoft.net/) in addition to SysInternals, too many to bother listing separately.

Answer (score 2):

I work with a lot of MS-SQL installs so I always have a copy of the old (no longer shipped) odbcping.exe. Last Microsoft SQL version to ship it was SQL Server 2000 (afaicr).

Very useful to determine if there's a problem with a SQL Instance.

```
usage: odbcping [-S Server | -D DSN] [-U Login Id] [-P Password]
```

Answer (score 2):

[moveable python](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/movpy/)

Comment: I can't understand why this isn't upvoted yet (?!).

Answer (score 1):

You can get UBCD4WIN on a thumbdrive

http://www.ubcd4win.com/

Answer (score 1):

Installer for AVG anti-virus.

Answer (score 1):

VPC 2007 and Two VHD's:

- XP Clean & patched / template box
- XP Loaded with tools and goodies

Answer (score 1):

I just loaded up my thumb drive with:

- 7-zip portable
- Autoruns
- Eraser portable
- Filezilla portable
- Firefox portable
- JkDegrag portable
- Process Explorer
- Putty
- Truecrypt
- Vim
- VLC portable
- WinDirStat portable

I have another thumb drive that is a bootable live Linux which comes in handy for gparted, dd, etc.

Answer (score 1):

sysinternals was already mentioned, but I wanted to point out [Desktops](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx) explicitly. It's an awesome tool when it works.

> Desktops allows you to organize your
>   applications on up to four virtual
>   desktops. Read email on one, browse
>   the web on the second, and do work in
>   your productivity software on the
>   third, without the clutter of the
>   windows you’re not using. After you
>   configure hotkeys for switching
>   desktops, you can create and switch
>   desktops either by clicking on the
>   tray icon to open a desktop preview
>   and switching window, or by using the
>   hotkeys.

Answer (score 1):

I know linux has been mentioned, but [DamnSmallLinux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/) has a VM version > 50 Meg's it's pretty awesome.

Answer (score 1):

For disk usage, I've seen utilities that use treemap visualization mentioned, but not the ancient, small, and unfortunately named [Scanner](http://www.steffengerlach.de/freeware/) (distributed as scn2.zip).

I find Scanner's sunburst chart much easier to read than treemaps, even if it lacks some of the features and speed of things like WinDirStat and SequoiaView.

Answer (score 1):

Use TiddlyWiki as a notebook: http://www.tiddlywiki.com/.

Ideal for carrying all your system-administration notes around on a stick. A full-featured wiki with wiki markup, links and tags in a single self-modifying html file.

Answer (score 1):

OpenOffice! It's not perfect, but darned handy. There's a portable version too.

This way if I get to a machine that has some budget version of Microsoft Office, or heaven forbid MS Works, installed I have tools that I am used to readily at hand.

Answer (score 1):

[Spacemonger v1.4](http://www.sixty-five.cc/download/) for tracking down large files/directories. Free, small and colourful.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.pendriveapps.com/

Answer (score 0):

Right now I have a 16GB OCZ Rally2 which I find dead handy. I keep lots of the tools mentioned above on it (in portable app form, mostly).

I've got the contents of some useful OSs on there: notably Windows XP, Server 2003, and also the Win 7 Beta. I created a partition that is compatible with W7 too so I can install directly without an optical disc. Dead handy for testing on laptops with varied hardware configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Tor -- you never know when you're going to need Web access that is free from cookies, Java, and other plug-ins.

Answer (score 0):

[JkDefrag v3.36](http://www.kessels.com/Jkdefrag/) - Better than the Native Windows disk degfragmenter. It can run from your USB drive. And best of all, it's FREE!

Comment: Superseded by www.mydefrag.com and now at 4.0.  Unfortunately, it's install-only but there's only one directory so you can zip it up and run that portably.

Comment: I stick to jkdefrag - mydefrag seems comparitively bloated.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [PC Repair/Toolkit](http://dailycupoftech.com/usb-drive-systems/3)

For reference:

- DCoT Menu
- Active@ ISO Burner
- AutoCompress
- Brute Benchmark
- CCleaner
- CDmage
- DriveImage XML
- Double Killer
- DTaskManager
- encopy
- Eraser
- ERUNT
- explore2fs
- File Assassin
- Filemon
- Hash
- HDDScan
- ICE ECC
- LC ISO Creator
- LSASecretsView
- NTREGOPT
- Patcher
- PMMon
- ProcessExplorer
- ProduKey
- Regmon
- Restoration
- Roadkil’s CommTest
- Roadkil’s Disk Image
- Rootkit Revealer
- SequoiaView
- System Information for Windows
- TweakUI
- Universal Extract
- Virtual CD Control Panel
- What Changed?
- Why Reboot?
- WirelessKeyView

Answer (score 0):

If you need to view/edit XML files of any type I highly recommend [First Object XML Editor](http://www.firstobject.com/dn_editor.htm).

Lightweight, no install, tree-view/editor synchronisation, syntax highlighting, and best of all a customizable Indent option (F8) to make sense of crazy Microsoft config files ;)

Answer (score 0):

Drive Snapshot disk imaging tool:

http://drivesnapshot.de/

No installation necessary, so you can just run the EXE on any host (Windows) to create a disk image to an external drive or network location.

Answer (score 0):

I have a bootable Ubuntu USB thumb drive(recently updated to 9.04), It has saved Data from many dead laptops and PCs.

Answer (score 0):

I like this USB software package -- http://portableapps.com/

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering... How big is that flash disk supposed to be? I myself have one that is 32 GB and there's a lot that you can fit on that. ;-)
If you use it on a system that can boot from USB, you might even consider installing a complete operating system on it, to run from USB. (Most likely going to be Linux.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of SIW (System Information for Windows). Lets you check a lot of computer information from a small exe file that fits on a thumb drive. It's got a free version as well which has always done everything I needed it to.

Answer (score 0):

I would add the following:

1. Tunnelier
2. KeePass

Answer (score 0):

Clonezilla Live, Knoppix and Trinity Rescue Kit are great for larger usb drives.
I edit the syslinux.cfg file so all 3 are bootable.

Answer (score 0):

**[Pendrivelinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/)**: make your thumb drive bootable!

They also have *persistent* installs now: your-whole-pc-on-a-stick ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I like to mention two old-school apps I use:

1. Windows NT 3.5 File Manager (winfile.exe). A single file that gives me raw access to the file system. For 2000/XP use the version that came with NT4 Service 4. Under Vista/7 the original version doesn't run anymore, but there is a patched version at
   http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~davidsch/vistafm/
2. 4NT, a powerful command line interpreter, for the cases when Powershell is not installed.
   Sadly, the vendor discontinued it.

Answer (score 0):

iperf and wireshark are good.   Not sure why you'd use the other sniffer when Wireshark is around.

Answer (score 0):

Win7 install/PE and ghost32 for PE.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably find windows boxes unusable with FAR manager, or any OFM.