# Suggestions for recovery toolkit

Tags: windows

For someone looking after a small 50 Windows PC network (Mainly XP - some Vista), what is a good set of recovery tools that can put installed on a USB drive (or perhaps CD?) to enable us to troubleshoot / recover / reboot troublesome PC's?

Answer (score 4):

The biggie for me is SpinRite from Steve Gibson ([grc.com](http://grc.com)). Saved many an ailing disk drive with it.

Answer (score 4):

The entire SysInternals suite has saved me multiple times.
memtest is also brilliant as is spinrite.

Answer (score 2):

How homogeneous is the setup? If you've got a lot of identical hardware, having a generic disk image goes a long way...

Also one or more of the following:

- UBCD and/or UBCD for Windows (a.k.a. UBCD4Win)
- SpinRite
- the aforementioned disk image
- Some sort of PE-type disk (i.e. BartPE)

These are some of the biggies. UBCD4Win and BartPE can be configured to have all sorts of stuff like a good anti-virus program, CCleaner, etc. Alternately you could have a USB drive with something like ClamWin portable, CCleaner, and other portable utilities.

I recently came across [Avira AntiVir Rescue System](http://www.free-av.com/en/tools/12/avira_antivir_rescue_system.html). I don't know how good it is yet, but it may be worth looking at.

Answer (score 2):

I've made some suggestions on [another answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/261/good-tools-that-fit-on-a-thumb-drive/629#629):

- DOS boot with CDROM
- Small BartPE with Ghost - run Win32 applications to test the computer, and transfer files off a dying harddisk with NTFS
- memtest86 - test RAM
- Offline NT Password Recovery boot - clear local administrator password when lost