# Tech Tool Bundle

Tags: untagged

Is this tool any good ...Power Suite

I found it [here](http://www.petri.co.il/powersuite2009lp.html) on Petri.co.it which is a pretty good source for IT information.

Is there one you guys can recommend?

Comment: Come on guys...wtf! How the heck do I know if I am getting the right thing?

Comment: Probably comes across as self-serving spam, though a look at your rep should kill that notion...

Comment: I know right...narrow-minded with the power to vote!

Comment: why don't you update your question to more accurately reflect your question saying what purposes you want to use the tool and maybe you will get some responses.

Comment: @ Wayne:  Agreed.

Comment: How about telling us what the software does, what you want to use it for, etc. We're not mind readers, and I don't think any of us are keen to download and install an unknown piece of software just to find out!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are asking correctly, then this question heavily overlaps with these.

- [Good tools that fit on a thumb drive](https://serverfault.com/questions/261/good-tools-that-fit-on-a-thumb-drive)
- [Tools a Windows administrator cannot live without](https://serverfault.com/questions/3482/tools-a-windows-administrator-cannot-live-without)
- [Tools a Unix administrator cannot live without](https://serverfault.com/questions/3478/tools-a-unix-administrator-cannot-live-without)
- [Server room survival kit?](https://serverfault.com/questions/2382/server-room-survival-kit)